# Why is this prime number generator printing undefined at the end?

Tags: javascript, undefined, primes

This is the code I have written which works fine, but the thing is that I am facing this `undefined` at the end.

```js
var isPrim = function(num) {
  var FG = true
  
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      FG = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  return FG
}

var primeNumbers = function(range) {
  for (let i = 3; i <= range; i++) {
    if (isPrim(i)) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}

console.log(primeNumbers(30));
```

This is the output in the bowser console:

[image: This is the output in the bowser console]

Comment: because primeNumbers returns nothing

Comment: What should i do ? To get rid of this, I mean how can I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Don’t log `primeNumbers(30)`.

Comment: okay I got this @SebastianSimon 
Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

```
var isPrim = function (num) {
      var FG = true
      for (let i = 2; i < num ; i++) {
        if ( num % i == 0) {
          FG = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      return FG
    }
    function primeNumbers(range) {
      for (let i = 3; i <= range; i++) {
        if (isPrim(i)) {
          console.log(i);
        }
      }
    }
    primeNumbers(20)
```

> It's because `var primeNumbers = function (range)` have no return `value` and I was tyring to log its return value, which is `undefined` at the end
>   Making simple call to function do solve this problem
>   Thanks who helped me out to solve this